# MySQL finding total sale of items of varying quantity and price

Tags: php, html, mysql

Essentially I'm trying to create an HTML table that displays a variety of items from a table in **MySQL** - regarding books and book sales. Basically I need

1. To find the total dollar amount sales each book which these books can be the same book but vary in **price**, and each sale varies in **quantity**. As of now, I've successfully created a loop in PHP to display such table and it looks like this:
   [image]

Unfortunately, the total sales price calculation is incorrect and I'm attempting to figure out why as I suspect it's something to do with my query.

Here is the table in question:
[image]

As you can see in the table, the same book can appear a variety of times, and have different quantities and unit prices. Some of my calculations are correct, others however are incorrect. Book ID **103** for example is incorrect.

Here's my HTML Code and thanks again for trying tp help me sort this out!:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
        <h2> <a class="head" href="base.php" style="text-decoration: none;">Database Project</a> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm main" href="login.php" role="button">Sign Out</a></h2>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Book Report:</h1><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Sale Price</th>
    
            </tr>
            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Zion");
            if ($conn-> connect_error){
                die("Connection Failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
            }
            $sql = "SELECT ID,Title,(SELECT Sum(Quantity) from Sale where BookId = Book.id ) as Quantity,(SELECT Sum(UnitPrice) from Sale where BookId = Book.id ) as Price from Book";
            $result = $conn-> query($sql);
            if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["ID"] . "</td><td>". $row["Title"]."</td><td>". $row["Quantity"]. "</td><td>". "$".$row["Price"]. "</td></tr>";
                }
                echo"</table>";
            }
            $conn-> close()
            ?>
            <!-- Generate a report that for each book, displays the book id, the book title, 
            the quantity and the total sales price, sorts by the book id in increasing order; -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you need Sum(Quantity*price)  ?

Comment: Hmmm you may be right, any idea how I would implement that?

Comment: just multiply the two - select sum(quantity*price) from sale .. etc

Comment: Also why sub queries ? may by `select  ID,Title, sum(Quantity) as sold, sum(Quantity * UnitPrice) as 'total sales' from Sale  group by id`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sql query using a join will help you to achieve your goal. The query retrieves for each Book (grouping by `Book.Id` and `Book.Title`), the total sold stored in `Quantity` and the `Price` at each sale, determined by multiplying the amount of a particular book by the unit price of each book at that time.

```sql
SELECT 
    Book.ID,
    Book.Title,
    SUM(Sale.Quantity) as Quantity,
    SUM(Sale.UnitPrice*Sale.Quantity) as Price
FROM
    Sale 
INNER JOIN
    Book on Book.Id = Sale.BookId
GROUP BY
    Book.ID, Book.Title
```

I have used the same column names, so this should work as is in your php code eg:

```php
$sql="SELECT Book.ID, Book.Title, SUM(Sale.Quantity) as Quantity, SUM(Sale.UnitPrice*Sale.Quantity) as Price FROM Sale INNER JOIN Book on Book.Id = Sale.BookId GROUP BY Book.ID, Book.Title";
```